# ASP.NET -Oracle-- Connection no more possible after certain amount of existing connections

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

We've got an ASP.NET application working with with Oracle database. To connect to the database we've used the basic ways:

```
OracleConnection con= new OracleConnection(....;
OracleCommand cmd=new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection=con;
cmd.CommandText=....;
```

I have no idea why but after 14-15 users are logged in to the application no additional user can log in and the application refuses to log in. I don't have any clue as to where I can start investigating except for the connection string. Here's how the connection string looks like:

```
        "User ID=SSPF_WEB_EDITION;Data Source=SSPF;Persist Security Info=False;Password=123;Validate Connection=true; Connection TimeOut=15;Pooling=False;
```

I thought maybe this issue is related with the "Pooling=False" option?

EDIT: We use Oracle's ODP.NET. Here's what we have in the log:
"TNS:listener could not find available handler witht matching protocol stack "

Comment: What do your logs say? Surely you've got an error logged somewhere.

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this post to check connection limits... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162255/how-to-check-the-maximum-number-of-allowed-connections-to-an-oracle-database

Comment: Why do you disable Connection Pooling? As far as I know this pooling is unvaluable to get under control the number of connections opened by a program

Comment: Here's what I got from the queries the link you directed provides:Currently, 196 out of 928 connections are used.

Comment: @Steve- I was suspecting that to cause the problem, so you also think this can be the cause?

Comment: Given the error I'm not sure, but if you try to remove the Pooling=False then check out this [very useful article](http://blog.ilab8.com/2011/09/02/odp-net-pooling-and-connection-request-timed-out/)

Comment: Also look at this thread on the Oracle Forum https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1193538

Comment: You can check this article http://zhefeng.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/ora-12516-error-tnslistener-could-not-find-available-handler-with-matching-protocol-stack/ or this article http://shettymayur.blogspot.no/2011/07/ora-12516-tnslistener-could-not-find.html.  They both say the same:  you are at the limits of your PROCESSES setting in the database.  There are many ways to get around that, the simplest one being to increase the limit :-).