# Can't obtain connection with the DB due to very long schema validation and connection reset afterwards

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have an app where I use Hibernate/Oracle 11g XE/Jboss6.2 and I am having trouble starting up the application on my homolog server at DigitalOcean (Jboss and Oracle xe installed locally).

Running everything on my dev machine I have no problem at all and it starts in about 30s, but every time I try to start my app at DO it takes about 10 minutes on [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator and afterwards I get javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection.

Even if I point my local jboss to my DO Oracle instance, it works fine. The only difference between my machine and the server is the OS (Windows vs Ubuntu).

Can someone please give me some direction?

Hibernate configs:

```
hibernate.dialect=com.foo.config.Oracle11gCustomDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=false
hibernate.generate_statistics=false
hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
hibernate.connection.defaultNChar=true
hibernate.connection.charSet=utf-8
hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8
hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=com.foo.config.OracleNamingStrategy
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

DataSource Config:

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/OracleDSJNDI" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</connection-url>
    <driver>OracleDriver</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>user</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <blocking-timeout-millis>5000</blocking-timeout-millis>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
</datasource>
```

Stacktrace:

```
16:39:49,749 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) HHH000400: Using dialect: com.foo.config.Oracle11gCustomDialect
16:39:49,768 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
16:39:50,383 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
16:39:50,391 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
16:39:50,457 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.1.Final-redhat-1
16:39:51,464 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) HHH000229: Running schema validator
16:39:51,464 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
16:48:16,065 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:288)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:246)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:781)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:344)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:397)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:365)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:302)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:139)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) [hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:146) [hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:512) [hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1797) [hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338) [spring-orm-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) [spring-orm-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:428) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:260)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:199) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:211) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:227) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1122) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:366) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:752) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:366) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        ... 50 more

16:48:16,115 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) HHH000319: Could not get database metadata: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/OracleDSJNDI
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) [hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:146) [hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:512) [hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1797) [hibernate-core-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.15.Final.jar:4.2.15.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338) [spring-orm-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) [spring-orm-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/OracleDSJNDI
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:390)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:302)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:139)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000658: Unexpected throwable while trying to create a connection: null
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:377)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:397)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:365)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:288)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:246)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:781)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:344)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:428) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:260)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.send(DataPacket.java:199) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NetOutputStream.flush(NetOutputStream.java:211) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:227) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1122) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:366) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:752) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:366) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
        ... 50 more
```

Comment: are you sure that's the only difference. how about available memory, max_memory parameter, cpu cores.....

Comment: Thinking about hardware, you are right. My dev machine is considerable better, but if I swap the database to use a H2 one, it works fine at the server. I simply don't get why it takes so long on schema validation.

Comment: Try doing a ping to IP_ADDRESS from your DO server

Comment: ip_address is localhost, I dunno why I omitted that. sorry. And yes, I can ping it.

Comment: which parts of it taking long?

Comment: This line is the one which takes long: `16:39:51,464 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the solutions in the following question?

[Oracle 11g connection reset error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464963/oracle-11g-connection-reset-error)

One particular answer had to do with the following comment:

> I could get it resolved by adding this parameter to the Hotspot JVM:
>   -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom

This issue does not affect windows, so it might be similar to what you are facing.

Comment: I really didn't expect this to work, but it actually did and I have no idea why. Thanks for this!