# Sqoop import failiing

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to run parallel sqoop Jobs in hadoop cluster however we see that during parallel runs the sqoop Jobs are failing with the following error.

```
16/11/11 09:24:59 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:682)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.makeConnection(OracleManager.java:327)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:744)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:767)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manage
```

The error seems to happening only when multiple jobs run in hadoop. I was searching the similar error and have come across these links. but the point is how can we accommodate that in sqoop Jobs.

[Oracle JDBC intermittent Connection Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327220/oracle-jdbc-intermittent-connection-issue).

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved after adding the property -Dmapred.child.java.opts="-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom".

Details of the issue is provided by [Oracle JDBC intermittent Connection Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327220/oracle-jdbc-intermittent-connection-issue)

and

[Oracle 11g connection reset error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464963/oracle-11g-connection-reset-error/25562756#25562756)

Kudos to the answers provided by the guys in the link.