# Connection Reset Error on Weblogic

Tags: oracle, weblogic

in my company i using Weblogic 10.3.6.0 on OEL 6.5 for connecting to a Oracle database in another location when i try to connect with weblogic to db i getting that error

```
    Error encountered:

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:467)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
        at utils.dbping.main(dbping.java:204)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:167)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:300)
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:106)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:315)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:260)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:185)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:102)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.receive(T4C8TTIdty.java:669)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.doRPC(T4C8TTIdty.java:578)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1166)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:322)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:94)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
        at utils.dbping.main(dbping.java:205)
```

so i change the SID to an invalid SID and get that error

```
Error encountered:

java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
        at utils.dbping.main(dbping.java:204)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:395)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
        ... 7 more
```

from that i found my connection to database is OK

i try that from other servers in my company and Weblogic 12c with JDK 8 and get "Connection Reset" error again

i try in my local Weblogic on Windows OS and get success
So... What can i dooo

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check a few things like :

- is the connection successful from console when you try to test the
  datasource?
- is there any firewall restricting the connection between your DB and Weblogic server.
- what is the driver that you are using for your production and is it
  the same as of your windows PC?
- is this happening everytime or is it an intermittent issue?

check the below thread for some more hints :
[Oracle 11g connection reset error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464963/oracle-11g-connection-reset-error)

Comment: 1. i check the connection from console and get same error
2. i connect from windows clients in same network and connect with OCI connection successfully
3. i using "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" and yes it's same in my windows client
4. yes it's happen everytime