# parameter for setting for user connections in Oracle

Tags: oracle

what is the parameter  for setting no. of oracle user connections in windows,
how parameter sessions and Process are related to user connections parameter

Comment: Have a look at the [`sessions`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/SESSIONS.html) parameter (as described in https://stackoverflow.com/q/162255/230471). The documentation also mentions processes. However this is really a [DBA question](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: on sessions, connections, and processes https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5671284058977