# Php Application takes Exact 16 mins to connect Oracle Database

Tags: php, oracle, database-connection, sqlplus

I'm using application developed in PHP and Oracle Database.
First few requests are processing properly, But after that it takes exact 16 mins to connect database through application.

For Example:
Lets consider, we received 10 request and all the request are connecting to database without any delay and processed properly. when we receive 11th request, it takes exactly 16 mins to connect database.

Once its started to take 16 mins to connect database, then for each and every request it takes same 16 mins to connect database. But we are able to ping or telnet to the server. Also we are able to connect database using `sqlplus` cmd (oracle client) without any delay.

If we restart the PHP, Then its working fine for whole day. Its processing all the request without any delay.

I can't identify, why its happening and how it takes exact 16 mins to connect database from application?

> I'm using PHP7-FPM and Oracle12c

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162255/how-to-check-the-maximum-number-of-allowed-connections-to-an-oracle-database/162381

Comment: @mitkosoft  Thanks, But the link you shared about the number connection allowed in oracle. But my problem is different.

Comment: Even If it is a Max connection issue, How come it takes exact 16 mins to connect database all the time.

Comment: what `SELECT CONNECT_TIME FROM SCHEMA_NAME.DBA_PROFILES;` says?

Comment: @mitkosoft As I checked, there is no such column in DBA_PROFILES. It contains only following columns Profile, Resource_Name, Resource_Type, Limit, Common, Inherited, Implict

Comment: did you try with `sys` account?

Comment: @mitkosoft Yes I tried, But Still I'm getting the same. even the account is different, But table will be same only right?